# Getting error while injecting $uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting error when I try to inject $uibModal to my new state.
In other states it works properly. What can be the cause of the error?

Error log

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=49d19463-4701-4df9-ba96-5053f03a665bProvider%20%3C-%2049d19463-4701-4df9-ba96-5053f03a665b
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:43
at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:40)
at angular.min.js:43
at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:40)
at ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3656
at Object.r [as forEach] (angular.min.js:8)
at Object.resolve (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3652)
at Object.$modal.open (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:4256)
at b.$scope.showNotification (NotificationsController.js:19)
```

My controller

```
angular.module('EProc.Notifications')
.controller('notificationsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal',
    function($scope, $http, $uibModal){

        $http.get('/api/notification/lastmsg').then(function(result) {
            console.log('last 10 notifications--------------------');
            console.log(result);
            $scope.lastNotifications = result.data.content;
            $scope.newMessages = result.data.newMessages;
        });

        $http.get('/api/notification/messages').then(function(result) {
            console.log('all notifications--------------------');
            console.log(result);
            $scope.allNotifications = result.data.content;
        });

        $scope.showNotification = function(id) {
            $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                size: 'md',
                templateUrl: 'client/components/notifications/tmpl/notificationModal.html',
                controller: 'notificationModalCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    id: id
                }
            });
        }
    }
])
.controller('notificationModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'id', '$uibModalInstance',
    function($scope, id, $uibModalInstance){
        $http.get('/api/notification/message/' + id).then(function(result) {
            $scope.notification = result.data;
        })
}]);
```

mainApp.js

```
var eProcApp = angular.module('EProc',
[
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'smart-table',
    'ngTagsInput',
    'EProc.Common',
    'EProc.Profile',
    'EProc.Purchasers',
    'EProc.Supply',
    'EProc.Tenders',
    'EProc.Notifications'
]);

eProcApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('myprofile', {
            url: '/myprofile',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/profile/tmpl/profileShortDetails.html',
            controller: 'profileDetailsCtrl'
        })

        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/annualPlans.html'
                },
                'itemstable@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/procurementPlan.html',
                    controller: 'annualProcPlanCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('purchasers', {
            url: '/purchasers/:purchaserId',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/purchasers.html',
                    controller: 'purchasersListCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('purchasers.procplan', {
            url: "/procplan",
            templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/procurementPlan.html',
            controller: 'procurementPlanCtrl'
        })

        .state('purchasers.children', {
            url: "/children",
            templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/childrenPartiesList.html',
            controller: 'childrenPurchasersCtrl'
        })

        .state('procplan', {
            url: '/procplan/:purchaserId',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/procurementPlan.html',
                    controller: 'procurementPlanCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('procitem', {
            url: '/procitem/:itemId',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/procurementItem.html',
            controller: 'procurementItemCtrl'
        })

        .state('search', {
            url: '/procitem/search/:page?searchText',
            params: {'filter': {}},
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/searchProcItems.html',
                    controller: 'searchProcItemsCtrl'
                },
                'search-results@search': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/components/purchase/tmpl/search/resultsSectionsView.html',
                    controller: 'procItemSearchResultsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('favgroups', {
            url: '/favgroups',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/supply/tmpl/favoriteGroups.html',
            controller: 'favoriteGroupsCtrl'
        })

        .state('favorites', {
            url: '/favorites/:gswId',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/supply/tmpl/favoritesList.html',
            controller: 'favoritesListCtrl'
        })

        .state('proposals', {
            url: '/proposals',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/supply/tmpl/commProposalsList.html',
            controller: 'commProposalListCtrl'
        })

        .state('proposal', {
            url: '/proposal/:procItemId',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/supply/tmpl/commProposal.html',
            controller: 'commProposalCtrl'
        })

        .state('tenders', {
            url: '/tenders/',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/tenders/tmpl/tendersList.html',
            controller: 'tendersListCtrl'
        })

        .state('announcement', {
            url: '/announcement/:announcementId',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/tenders/tmpl/singleAnnouncementView.html',
            controller: 'viewAnnouncementCtrl'
        })

        .state('watchlist', {
            url: '/watchlist/',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/supply/tmpl/keywordMatchWatchList.html',
            controller: 'kwMatchWatchListCtrl'
        })

        .state('notifications', {
            url: '/notifications',
            templateUrl: 'client/components/notifications/tmpl/notifications.html',
            controller: 'notificationsCtrl'
        });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loginInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resolve` property values must be functions, ie

```
resolve: {
  id: function() { return id }
}
```